# Getting Ghost blog to display on subdomain blog.mysite.com rather than www or root domain

Tags: dns, hosting, ghost-blog

I have a Ghost blog running where the domain is set to www.mysite.com on their end and two CNAME entries set to the following: 
Host:www Points to: mysite.ghost.io 
Host: @ Points to: mysite.ghost.io.

I want to run the blog off of a subdomain, preferably blog.mysite.com and use www and the root of my domain to run a separate site hosted by my hosting service.

Would this involve simply changing the CNAME information on my host at iPage to the following. 
Host: blog Points to: mysite.ghost.io and removing the original two entries listed above?

Answer (score 0):

I think your assumption to just add a CNAME that points `blog` to `mysite.ghost.io`is correct. If you would like to only forward the `blog` subdomain the two entries for `www`and `@` are not needed. These entries should point to the separate hosted site.

You can find more information about how to use a custom domain with ghost.io here: https://ghost.org/blogs/domains/.